# Каким способом можно переопределить страницу приложения в django.contrib.admin?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, django

Хочу добавить дополнительный блок на страницу */admin/myapp* и в него поместить кнопки/cсылки, при нажатии которой, на сервере должен выполнятся код связанный с загрузкой/обновлением данных с внешнего ресурса в приложение.

Как переопределить эту страницу лишь для одного приложения и создать функцию-обработчик для этой кнопки?